# Custom text ellipsis in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to develop sth like Twitter does, show mutual followers

following below requirements:

- max 2 lines of text
- show as many user names as fits the space, and show "and ${otherUsers.length} others"

[image]

What's the best way to achieve that?
Do I need to do calculations for every user name and decide how many fits the screen? Or there is a better / simpler way to achieve that? Maybe a custom ellipsize callback or sth?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Worked in my personal project. So make sure at least 4 of the names are in a list and if more you ignore that by using `.take(4)` method of a list and concat that with your desired words.

```
...
var p = text.split('split your way`).take(4); //example

....
 Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
                              width: 2.5),
                          color: AppColors.primaryThemeColor,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  "assets/images/potrait.jpeg"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 40,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
                              width: 2.5),
                          color: AppColors.primaryThemeColor,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  "assets/images/support.jpeg"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 80,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
                              width: 2.5),
                          color: AppColors.primaryThemeColor,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                              image:
                              AssetImage("assets/images/user.jpeg"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 120,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: AppColors.secondaryThemeColor,
                              width: 2.5),
                          color: AppColors.whiteThemeColor,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                              image:
                              AssetImage("assets/images/airduka.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
///Point of concern
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
width: 180,
                child: Text( //perform if-else
                  'Followed by ${'Your name variables in alist'.take(4)} and 10 others',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,// Dont need this
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: I see you hardcoded 4 `.take(4)`. The thing is that I want be flexible here and show e.g. only 2 usernames if they are long.

Comment: Yes so instead of using `.take(4)`  just describe the width of the `SizedBox` of the text and count the max charachters you'd want and see the updated code

Comment: Counting characters is the best idea so far! Seems like not the most precise one, but should be more performant and simpler than calculating actual width